# How does one calculate the target outputs of neurons in hidden layers of a neural network?

Tags: neural-network

In a simple single-layer network, it is easy to calculate the target outputs of neurons, as they are identical to the target outputs of the network itself. However, in a multiple-layer network, I am not quite sure how to calculate the targets for each individual neuron in the hidden layers, because they do not necessarily have a direct connection to the final output and are most likely not given in the training data. How would one find these values?

I would not be surprised if I am missing something and am going about this incorrectly, but I would like to know nonetheless. Thanks in advance for any and all input.

Comment: This is a broad question. What exactly are you asking? How to calculate activations?

Comment: Have you looked over the backpropagation algorithm? Every article I've ever read goes over that in depth. Long story short: you don't. You backpropagate the error from the output node. The error of the output layer is calculated different from the hidden layers.

Comment: More how to calculate deltas for weight updates in learning rules. Many learning rules contain something along the lines of `(target output) - (real output)`. I just don't know how to find that target in hidden layers.

Comment: Ah,I see, Carcigenicate. I knew about backpropogation, I just didn't fully grasp the concept, apparently.

Comment: @emmc_1247 Read this pdf. It's the best simple guide I've ever found: https://www.fer.unizg.hr/_download/repository/BP_chapter3_-_bp.pdf It's overly simplified in parts, but it's a great intro.

Comment: @emmc_1247 Read page 18 over many times. It's a great breakdown. Point 4 answers your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [this great guide](https://www.fer.unizg.hr/_download/repository/BP_chapter3_-_bp.pdf) on pg. 18:

> 4. Calculate the Errors for the hidden layer neurons. Unlike the output layer we can’t 
>      calculate these directly (because we don’t have a Target), so we Back Propagate 
>      them from the output layer (hence the name of the algorithm). This is done by 
>      taking the Errors from the output neurons and running them back through the 
>      weights to get the hidden layer errors.

Or in other words, you don't. You *propagate* the activations from the input to the output, calculate the error of the output, then *backpropagate* the error from the output back to the input (thus the name of the algorithm).

In the unfortunate case that the link I posted goes down, it can be found by Googling "backpropagation algorithm 3".

Comment: Is there enough context in the small snippet I pasted to make sense on its own?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @emmc_1247 Np. Download that pdf! It changes addresses every once in awhile, so it can be hard to refind.